# Basic Ruby - Need simple explanation of what an if/else statement is doing

Tags: ruby

For a basic car class exercise, we were asked to create a drive method which should take an input for the number of miles driven, change the position accordingly and reduce the fuel at a rate of 20 miles per gallon.

I understand the basic concept of what I need to do and how an if/else statement works, but need help breaking down the if/else statement into more 'layman terms' as to what exactly is happening with the content.

```
def initialize
    @fuel = 10
    @distance = 0
end

def drive(miles)
    if (@fuel - miles/20.0) >= 0
        @distance += miles
        @fuel -= miles/20.0
    else
        @distance += @fuel * 20.0
        @fuel = 0
        puts "You're out of gas!"
    end
```

Comment: Maybe try removing the ruby syntax (the parans etc), translate the symbols to english (example, > becomes greater than etc) and read it like an english sentence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You initially set fuel to be a value of 10 and the distance to be 0.

When you drive `x` amount of miles (hence why miles is input), you have to see if you're out of gas.

If the amount of fuel minus the number of miles traveled, divided by 20, is greater than or equal to 0, we set the distance traveled to be the distance + the amount of miles traveled (`+=` is shorthand for `@distance = @distance + miles`). I do think that the `if` may need clarification though: is it "fuel - miles, then divided by twenty"? Or is it "fuel - miles/20", where order of operations comes into play?

Anywho, shorthand for `+=`:

```
@distance = @distance + miles
```

Then we set fuel to be the amount of fuel minus the amount of miles traveled, divided by twenty (`-=` is also shorthand, similar to before.)

```
@fuel = @fuel - miles/20.0
```

However, otherwise (the ELSE), we set distance to be

```
@distance = @distance + fuel *20
```

Then we set fuel to 0, and print out the string "You're out of gas!".

Comment: "Or is it "fuel - miles/20", where order of operations comes into play?" It's code he's trying to understand, so the order of operations will come into play. The code is going to interpreted as `miles/20` then the resulting value is subtracted from `fuel`, but when reading it out loud it's OK to gloss over the order as an assumption that it'll occur.

Comment: Thought so. I just wasn't sure if this was code he/she was given or code they had to come up with :)

Comment: Hi Ryan - this is the answer to the class problem, so I did not write this portion.

Comment: Thank you Tin Man and Ryan for your help! This helped tremendously!